# excel formula to get datetime in format '20-oct-2015 8:34:59.000000 PM'

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have excel sheet where I need to enter todays datetime in format `20-oct-2015 8:34:59.000000 PM`. I used `NOW()` function in excel but got it in format `10/20/2015 11:48`. can someone please tell me the formula to extract the data in required format.

Comment: Using the formula `m/d/yyyy h:mm.ss.000` will get you precision up to milliseconds, but Excel does not seem to support anything beyond this out of the box.  Why do you need microsecond precision?  See [this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095407/display-milliseconds-in-excel) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Type **=NOW()**  in the required cell

Press enter

Right click on that cell .

Go to "Formats cells"

[image]
Go to numbers tab (first tab)

Go to custom category(last line)

There you can see a sample and "Type"

In that "Type " row just put(copy and paste) the following line as shown in the figure

**[$-409]d-mmm-yyyy h:mm:ss.000 AM/PM**
[image: screen shot]

Press ok.