# CSV file in excel format displays incomplete

Tags: python, excel, csv

I am using Python v2.7 on Windows 7 OS.
My goal is using Python to generate a CSV file which contains date, time, etc.

The question is, the CSV outputs of time are different btw txt format and excel format. Here are some details.

If I use txt to open CSV file, it is good. The output is like: 2016-03-07,15:16:04.003000,...

But when I open the same CSV file with excel, the output of time is not fully displayed: [image: in excel]
You may notice from the top line that, the full display of time is actually there. But from row 2, it is incomplete.

Please advice. Thanks!

Comment: format cells in excel file correspondingly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095407/display-milliseconds-in-excel

Comment: oops! http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/316511-can-i-display-time-up-microseconds-excel.html - you can show only milliseconds in Excel

Comment: Thanks for the input. So is there a way to display full time?

Comment: you can try to display it as a string, but you won't be able then to apply date/time formulas on that column

Comment: Well...actually, the question I posted is coded under string~ :) we think the same, but problem is there anyway... :(

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, select the "time value" cell and mouse right click --> Format Cell --> Number --> custom --> input Type as mm:ss.000000

[Customize number display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAoDE.png)

Comment: Thanks for the input Yunhe. I tried it out. The target is fully display 3:16:04. I customize the format on Format Cells, but it seems that only 16:04.### customized, I did see '3' in there... :'(

Comment: I think I figure it out, I just modify the last step on your idea. Thank you Yunhe!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by 'select the "time value" cell and mouse right click --> Format Cell --> Number --> custom --> input Type as **h:mm.ss**. Thanks for the hint from Yunhe!