# Format Time Elapsed and get average

Tags: excel

How can I format time in excel sheet and get average?

```
00:00:00.2543348
00:00:00.3553345
```

Then in another column I would like to display the average.

Comment: Excel only recognized three decimal places to a second. If you want more, then treat a second as **1**, not 1/86400 and the decimal portion as a double.

Comment: You could store the milliseconds in a different column and calculate your average accordingly.

Comment: This answered my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095407/display-milliseconds-in-excel